# Is there a Chrome(ium) alternative for the Firefox "Self-Destructing Cookies" extension?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I am huge fan of the Firefox extension https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/ and am looking for something like this for chrome.

Note: I am **not** looking for some random cookie deleting/managing extension. I am looking for an extension that allows cookies but immediately deletes them after leaving sites. As close to the mentioned extension as it can be.

Comment: as [Tab Cookies](https://superuser.com/a/592197/403979) seems to be dead for 6 years now, i suggest [Cookie AutoDelete](https://github.com/mrdokenny/Cookie-AutoDelete). it is a pretty young project and can't clear LocalStorage yet but looks promising and is available for [Chrome(ium)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-autodelete/fhcgjolkccmbidfldomjliifgaodjagh) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/).

Comment: @SergeStroobandt according to several [reviews on Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies-1/reviews/) *Self Destroying Cookies* looks really suspicious to me!

Comment: ...AND meanwhile *Cookie AutoDelete* has pretty matured and can also clear LocalStorage for a while now (Firefox 58+). - just at Chrome(ium based browsers) it still can't clear LocalStorage, but no extension is able to do so [because of Google/Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78093).

Comment: As a [Self-Destructing Cookies](https://addons.palemoon.org/addon/sdc-moon-edition/) user on [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/), for the Chrome/Chromium and [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) browsers I would recommend using the [open-source](https://github.com/Cookie-AutoDelete/Cookie-AutoDelete) [Cookie Autodelete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-autodelete/fhcgjolkccmbidfldomjliifgaodjagh).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Tab Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-cookies/iahecghojagkcoehfhfknajofkokndjm) looks like it would fit the bill.

From the description:

> This extensions deletes all the cookies created in a tab (which are not used by other tabs) when you close the tab. In this way your privacy is guaranteed.
>
> For example, as long as you stay on gMail, you are logged in, but once you close that tab (and all the others which are or have been on a Google site) the tracking cookies of Google disappear. Same for Facebook, once you close all the tabs which opened Facebook, its cookies disappear, so other sites cannot track you around the web.

Comment: Excellent addon with a not so excellent name. It handles the cookies domain based and not tab based. So the name is misleading or not descriptive enough. It's also probably the reason I not found it myself. Anyway seems to be working exactly like I like it to thanks ;)

Comment: I installed it and am finding it pretty easy to use. The phrase "which are not used by other tabs" does seem like a tiny loophole, so it would seem important to not keep too many tabs open at once. (That's a bad habit I have which I'm trying to break using the Tabs Outliner extension.)

Comment: @JonCoombs: i accidentally came here because of *Self-Destructing Cookies* (so i don't use Chromium myself) but maybe you can workaround this issue by don't accepting third-party cookies. -- after having a look at *Tab Cookies* it seems there is [a especial setting](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/qO5b5GuA9v7gEkLCOIzAtPBUpBWTDdph14krCxatnt0fqgH5RJe5fiSWaQoluaVxTyK_A-z27fI=s640-h400-e365) similar to [Self-Destructing Cookies](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/98/98902.png) to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I can think of is the native behavior in Chrome, which can delete cookies as soon as you close the browser.

1. Go to `chrome://settings` (or open the **Settings** from the menu).
2. Open the advanced settings, by clicking **Show advanced settings...**

   [image]
3. Open the content settings, by clicking **Content settings...**

   [image]
4. Select the option **Keep local data only until I quit my browser**

   [image]

Comment: While you sort of acknowledged it with your 'closest I can think of' lead in, this isn't what was asked for.

Comment: @mc0e: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many that are very close, but I decided that this one is closer than the rest. 
It's called [Vanilla Cookie Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vanilla-cookie-manager/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj?hl=en), and it uses a whitelist function for cookie-blocking. It also has a feature that lets you destroy all (non-whitelist) cookies on startup. That's what I use.

Oh, and on any page, if you hit the button, you can check your cookie jar to see how many you have and how many are actually from the sites you whitelisted. You can find buttons to destroy the non-whitelist cookies then and there, or to add the page to whitelist, or go to the control panel.